# Reading 50 CSV files

Tags: python

I want to read 50 CSV files and write down the results to a single CSV file. My current code reads only a single CSV file that is 1.csv and write the output to out.csv. How can I tweak this code ? Please help.

```
import csv

f1 = open("1.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(f1)
header = reader.next()
f2 = open("out.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(f2)

writer.writerow(header)
for row in reader:
    if row[8] == 'READ' and row[10] != '0000':
        writer.writerow(row)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: How are the files labeled and/or stored? Also your example code is not formatted correctly.

Comment: Hi, Thank You for a quick response. Files are stored in the same directory where 1.csv  is stored . All are csv files and they start with different number like some starts with 48 some with 2 etc

Comment: Are you only trying to get certain rows in the files or do you want everything in the files?

Comment: Just selective rows. As you can see from my code as it is for a single file '1.csv'. I only want rows with string READ and not 0000

Answer (score 1):

Try using [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to loop through the files, read it and then append it to the new file.

To search the file for lines with an identifier use re

```
import glob
import re

out = []
for fil in glob.glob("path/to/files/*.csv"):
    for line in open(fil,'r'):
        if re.search('READ',line):
            out.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to look into something like os in Python and walk through your directories of excel files working each one individually.   Instead of writing out to a new page each time a file is worked, you're going to append to the file that you are writing to.

This example will walk through all documents connected to the root tree finding all files in all directories.  This could be overkill if you have all your files in one directory.

```
import os

# traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and excel files as files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
    print((len(path) - 1) * '---', os.path.basename(root))
    for file in files:
        print(len(path) * '---', file)
```